# Display categories and subcategories from an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am using Laravel as my framework but it is not a laravel question, per se. From an array, I am trying to display results for each month, as follows:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>January</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>First result for january</td>
        <td>Second result for january</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>February</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>First result for february</td>
        <td>Second result for february</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In my controller I am getting the results as follows:

```
$results = Expense::whereBetween('date', array($start, $end))->get();
```

Where `$start` and `$end` are dates that I gather from my input, in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

In my view I display the results like this (example):

```
@foreach($results as $result)

    {!! $result->date !!} - {!! $result->expense !!} - {!! $result->amount !!}

@endforeach
```

But I would like to have it like in the above example. So, when in my input I select different months, also the view changes, so I cannot hard code it in. I basically need to change my foreach to display a month, with all results from that month below that, and then display the next month, and so on.

A nudge in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: I just want to double check your table format, are you sure you don't want each month to be a column instead of a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would group the results using [Laravel Collections methods](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-groupby):

```php
$results = Expense::whereBetween('date', array($start, $end))->get();
$results = $results->groupBy(function($expense) 
{
    return Carbon\Carbon::parse($expense->date)->month;
});
```

Then you will have your results in the following format:

```
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2708
  all: [
    1 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1427
      all: [
        App\Expense {#1410 …27},
        App\Expense {#3077 …27},
        App\Expense {#1408 …27},
        ...
      ],
    },
    2 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1428
      all: [
        App\Expense {#1310 …27},
        App\Expense {#3377 …27},
        App\Expense {#1308 …27},
        ...
      ],
    },
    3 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1429
      all: [
        App\Expense {#1810 …27},
        App\Expense {#3877 …27},
        App\Expense {#1808 …27},
        ...
      ],
    },
    ...
  ],
}
```

Each key will represent a month number.

Comment: Awesome stuff, I will look into it later :) Will accept your answer since it seems like this is the way to go, thanks :)